# Modifying a fusemount while mounted

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, fuse

I have a cloud account that is mounted using fuse-lib on Ubuntu 16.04.

I cannot gain access to this folder from users other than the user where mounted.

I know this is how fuse-lib is supposed to work and that you can pass option `-o allow_other` to circumvent this but I am unable to manually mount the drive.

The mount happens through software.

Short of hunting and recompiling the software (not ideal), I would like to find a way to manage the mount after it has been mounted.

Alternatively to somehow allow another user unrestricted access to the user's folders including mounts but that would be another question for another time.

Any relevant advice welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

#### Workaround

Install [`bindfs`](https://bindfs.org/). Then invoke as the original user:

```
bindfs -o allow_other /original/mountpoint /secondary/mountpoint
```

The contents of `/original/mountpoint` should appear under `/secondary/mountpoint` and other users should be able to use the latter path. Every access attempt to `/secondary/mountpoint` (no matter from which user) will be handled by a userspace process running with the privileges of the original user, therefore there's no longer a need to modify the original mount.

The obvious downside is there are now two daisy-chained FUSE filesystems instead of one. This may hit the performance.

You should read [these security concerns](https://www.cs.nmsu.edu/%7Epfeiffer/fuse-tutorial/html/security.html), especially:

> It's the responsibility of the user who mounts the filesystem to ensure inappropriate access privileges aren't being granted to other users.

If you managed to enable `-o allow_other` for `/original/mountpoint`, as you wanted to do, you would face the same concerns. It seems to me that my workaround doesn't make them worse; they now apply to `/secondary/mountpoint` instead of `/original/mountpoint`, but they are the same.

The software may not be able to unmount from `/original/mount` until you tell `bindfs` to unmount from `/secondary/mountpoint`. To do so, run as the original user:

```
fusermount -u /secondary/mountpoint
```